# How to format title of a test in the test.each api of jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

The each API in jest is quite convenient but I'm not sure on how to create a title when the rows consist of non-basic data types.

In the following example, I would like to name the test `test function ${f.name}` but I cannot seem to figure out how this can be done by "positionally injecting parameters"?

```js
const t1 = () => 't';
const t2 = () => 't';

test.each([t1, t2])('test function %???', f => { // what to use instead of %??? here ?
   console.log(`test function ${f.name}`);
   expect(f()).toBe('t');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `%p`. This symbol use [pretty-format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pretty-format) package to stringify any JavaScript value, even `function`. Take a look at [test.each(table)(name, fn, timeout)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#testeachtablename-fn-timeout).

E.g.

```js
const t1 = () => 't';
const t2 = () => 't';

test.each([t1, t2])('test function %p', (f) => {
  console.log(`test function ${f.name}`);
  expect(f()).toBe('t');
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/65042421/index.test.ts (15.895s)
  ✓ test function [Function t1] (15ms)
  ✓ test function [Function t2] (1ms)

  console.log src/stackoverflow/65042421/index.test.ts:5
    test function t1

  console.log src/stackoverflow/65042421/index.test.ts:5
    test function t2

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        17.14s
```